# Display boolean option with other names in view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a column in a database that I want a user to be able to set with an input field. Right now it is displaying as a selection list with the options true or false. Instead, I would like it to display two custom options called something else.

Including the using directives etc in case they are missing something.

In the view:

```
 @model (ProjectName).Models.(ModelName) 

 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Chipped, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Chipped)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Chipped, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public bool? Chipped { get; set; }
```

What is a good way to do this?

---

I have tried the suggestion I received in the comments.

The model then looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ChippedOptions1 { get => ChippedOptions; set => ChippedOptions = value; }
```

And the view like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Chipped, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Chipped, Model.ChippedOptions)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Chipped, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Error message:

> 'Model' does not contain a definition for 'Chipped' and no accessible
>   extension method 'Chippped' accepting a first argument of type 'Model'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: Create your own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (with (say) `Value=true, Text = "Yes"` etc and use `DropDownListFor()` to bind to `Chipped`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, could you be more detailed on how to achieve this?

Comment: You need to give more details (I cannot guess what the 3 values you want to display for the `true`, `false` and `null` values)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, In this case, I just want to use yes, no and not set.

Comment: Then Just add an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ChippedOptions : get; set; }` to your view model (it will contain 3 items with the text you want) and use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Chipped, Model.ChippedOptions)`

Comment: But how do I connect it to the row Chipped in the database when it is just named ChippedOptions in the model? Excuse my basic questions!

Comment: The `DropDownListFor()` code I showed you binds to `Chipped` (just as your `EditorFor()` also binds to `Chipped`)

Comment: I get an error where it says my model class does not contain the definition of "Chipped", possibly missing using directive or assembly reference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181824/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sandra).